# custom identity user and extending profile MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to extend the identity user data in separate table but its not populating.

```
  public class MyUserInfo
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

  }

  public class AppUser : IdentityUser<Int32, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>
  {

    public MyUserInfo MyUserInfo { get; set; }
 }

//Fetching the user data

var userStore = new UserStore<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>(db);
var userManager = new UserManager<AppUser, int>(userStore);

var user = userManager.FindById(1);
```

**user.MyUserInfo** showing the `null`. But in db, we have the respective user data.

I saw many post where without customization seems working but for me I modified id stored as integer and changed the table name.

Comment: Is this all the relative code? cause entity framework will not make any relation between tables like this

Comment: It's not quite that simple... but you can easily create a CustomMembershipProvider that matches your existing tables etc. It's worth it, imho. https://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/how-to-configure-custom-membership-and-role-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4/

Comment: @Robert you are talking about old `MembershipProvider` and the question is about newer Identity framework, and these are not the same.

Comment: @tmg I pasted the code only for appUser and Profile rest of the table like role etc is there. All is working fine. MyUserInfo data is not filling. see ref. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Comment: @Robert i am having issue with Identity framework

Comment: Is your problem creating the MyUserInfo table or populating it during registration?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich yes MyUserInf not populating when fetching the user details AppUser(IdentityUser). as per the ref link it should:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Comment: Your userinfo data will not be automatically populated when you fetch your user. You have to implement that in your account controller (or where ever you are fetching user data) using EF.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich yes I am doing the same. But as per the ref. blog it should populate automatically because it will create foreign key with AppUser. Not sure. Its normal cases, I want to create relation with AppUser to any tables.

Answer (score 6):

**The stock *Identity UserManager* does not automatically pull `UserInfo` (or any other table Entity with foreign key Navigation)**

You have extended the *Identity Schema*, but you have not extended the ***UserManager***.

None of the ***UserManager*** 's methods for getting user (e.g. `findbyid()`, `FindByIdAsync()`) retrieve "child" entities by Entity Framework Navigation.

Take a look at the **[GitHub FindByIdAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs#L202)**

```
    public virtual Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        var id = ConvertIdFromString(userId);
        return Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id.Equals(id), cancellationToken);
    }
```

The method only returns the User Entity. There is no functionality to check for an "child" Navigation tables, let alone pull them.

---

You can extend the ***UserManager*** by implementing such a method.

Otherwise, you will have to manually pull the child Entity after retrieving the `UserId`. This is how I did it:

```
            var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

            try
            {
                user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(UserId );
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }

            var userInfo = AuthContext.UserInfo.
                   FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.UserInfo_Id);
```

**Note:** I also had to make sure that my `ApplicationUser` had a foreign key for my `UserInfo` Entity:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [ForeignKey("UserInfo")]
    public int UserInfo_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
```

and in my model builder

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
          .HasRequired<UserInfo>(profile => profile.UserInfo);


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: I agree with you. UserManager will not automatically pull MyUserInfo. But I think you need to change User.Identity.GetUserId() to User.Identity.GetUserId<int>() since the pk is int.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich first of all thank you so much for your time. Yes I read your answer and doing the same things. But my concern was it should populate automatically as per this ms blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx . Anyway as your suggestion it should not so it many be in case of the customization. Thanks for your time again.

Comment: @Parwej, I didn't notice earlier what you're talking about. That article is inaccurate. If you take a look at the source code on GitHub, you'll see the method does nothing more than return user Entity `return Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id.Equals(id), cancellationToken);`  https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs#L202

Comment: @Parwej, I understand your confusion and updated my answer. I don't understand why MSDN would post something so clearly wrong. I hope this better explains.

Comment: @Parwej, leme know if the source code from GitHub helps? Or if you need further clarification. Also, if you want to make an extension method to UserManager, post that as a new Question. It's a good one. Show what you have tried.

Comment: @DaveAlperovich for now, I just create a property inside the AppUser and getting the profile data on demand. I don't want to change it because so many places I used. I will follow your approach in new project or any my sample project to test it.

Comment: @Parwej, I like that approach a lot. I intended to write an extension method, but I think I'm gona use your approach!

Comment: @DaveAlperovich i suggested above, used my own approach. But you given here other solution and for this you putted a lot efforts in this. So given bounty.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is not strictly about asp.net identity but about entity framework.
Since you get data from  `userManager.FindById(1)` but you do not get the relative data from `MyUserInfo` table cause the relation does not exist.

Change `MyUserInfo` entity to

```
public class MyUserInfo
{
    //change it from Id to AppUserId
    public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }   
    //add this virtual property
    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Then add migrations and update database. Entity framework will make the relation between tables and `AppUserId` will be the foreign key(code first relationship convention).

Comment: my assumption was same earlier but getting error with migration:  "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'App.Data.Entities.AppUser' and 'App.Data.Entities.MyUserInfo'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."

Comment: its cause entity framework can not decide which MyUserInfo.Id or AppUser.Id is the primary and which is the foreign key, did you try to rename as I did ?

Comment: I tried   **public class MyUserInfo
  {
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }

  }**